# Integrate third party page to my wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-thesis-theme

I am new in WordPress. I have purchased some sms from a company. Login link is: isms.sslwireless.com.

I want to integrate this application to my own page with removing header and footer information. I want to hide actual provider and his information. Could anyone help me? Is there have suitable plugin to do the same?

Comment: You probably want to do this my means of an HTTP API. Does this provider have any such thing?

Answer (score 0):

You Can do by use of **css**.

for eg:-

```
#footer
{
 display:none;
}
```